# Java image file path location is null

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

Trying to change the icon of my JFrame. I've tried multiple methods of getting the image that I want but none have worked I just get 'Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null' which I know means the file isn't there, but it is.

Here are two methods I've tried, and for the second one, yes, I have a folder created for that.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ECFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    public ECFrame() {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C://Users//jackk//eclipse-workspace//EasyChat//src//images//eclogotest.jpg");
        frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        
        frame = new JFrame("EC");
        frame.setSize(800,450);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ECFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    public ECFrame() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("src/images/eclogotest.jpg");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
        frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        
        frame = new JFrame("EC");
        frame.setSize(800,450);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't bother to try and debug the first one as it will be useless at time of deployment. As to the 2nd approach.. `src/images/eclogotest.jpg`, the Jar would not normally contain the `src` directory and the `String` should start with a `/`. But first check that it is **in the Jar.** To do that (lazily) on Windows, I'd rename the `.jar` to a `.zip` then open it to check. BTW: Load the image using `ImageIO.read(URL)`. It gives helpful output if the image is not found.

Comment: As stated, change `URL url = getClass().getResource("src/images/eclogotest.jpg");` to `URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/eclogotest.jpg");` and ensure that the resource is been included in the resulting Jar file (you can unzip it)

Comment: It might not have much to do with the problem itself, but aren't you initialising the `JFrame` *after* setting its icon?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't exported any Java projects yet so...should I export my project to get the Jar file or is it somewhere else.

Comment: *"I haven't exported any Java projects yet"* All the IDEs I use will build a Jar as a matter of course. Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* someone of a new comment.

Comment: Also, I think I'm doing this all wrong. I have my image stored in a package in my Eclipse project which I don't think is right and don't know where my Jar file is.

Comment: I'm not here to tutor people on using their IDE. Having said that I'll make a slight exception now. Select the option to 'build' or 'clean and build' the project and the location of the Jar should be mentioned in the output of the Eclipse console.

Answer (score -1):

I was Facing The Same issue but I am using Java Swing library for GUI in my case i just replaced the following statement

```
jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ICONS/icons8-burger-48.png")));
```

by

```
jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir)+("\\src\\main\\java\\projectname\\ICONS containing folder name\\icons8-burger-48.png")));
```

Comment: Neither the source directory nor your home directory will be there at runtime.